# Angular Material Date-Picker is not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to get date using Angular Material datepicker as mentioned bellow,

In `html`

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label>Custom calendar color</mat-label>
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker2 color="primary"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

In `app.module.ts`

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';

imports: [
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatNativeDateModule
],
```

In my `package.json`

> "dependencies": {
>           "@angular/animations": "^8.2.9",
>           "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
>           "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
>           "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
>           "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
>           "angular-mat-datepicker": "0.0.2",
>           "angular-material-datepicker": "^1.0.2",
>           "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
>           "ng-material-datetimepicker": "^1.19.2",
>         },

But the date picker icon is not working, even icon is not showing in the view. I have updated Angular material version as well but that didn't work. What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Try to import the mat-icon module

Comment: import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';

Comment: Now icon is working but as I mentioned above the placeholder does not work and also the calendar is displayed but properly not working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution for my problem.I just run bellow code and now everything works fine as I expected,

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Answer (score 9):

You also have to import `MatFormFieldModule` and `MatInputModule` to get it working.

Also don't forget to import `BrowserAnimationsModule`. Check out this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sa-xbn5hq-mxoo46)

Comment: Now icon is working but as I mentioned above the placeholder does not work and also the calendar is displayed but properly not working as expected

Comment: If you remove `mat-label` it will. Checkout: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants

Comment: ``<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>`` I changed like this that is also not working

Comment: Sorry, earlier I misunderstood your concern. Can you please point out the problems with each part: placeholder , calendar's behaviour etc.

Comment: Calendar is showing but it's view not showing properly and also the Placeholder is not working at all

Comment: Can you please take a look at StackBlitz link I shared in the answer. View seems fine to me in there and placeholder is also working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201086/discussion-between-rasindu-de-alwis-and-shaktimaan).

Answer (score 2):

Also import this link:

```
import { MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the `startView` and/or `[startAt]` attribute, this is how the Angular docs suggest to build up a simple datepicker in your html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker startView="year" [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: [startAt]="startDate" has nothing to do this toggling my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I have used material datepicker in angular 7. 
Go through this and hope it will resolve your issue.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatDatepicker} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
selector: 'app-date',
template: `

    <mat-form-field class="demo-full-width margin-top" [formGroup]="group">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (dateChange)="saveRange()"
               formControlName="datePicker" placeholder="Select Date">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

`,
styles: [],
})

export class DateComponent implements OnInit {

group: FormGroup;

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {
}

saveRange() {
    console.log(this.group.value);
}

}
```

Comment: what is ``@ViewChild(MatDatepicker) picker: MatDatepicker<Moment>;``

Comment: I have used to access Child Component in the Parent Component.  Also, I have passed Moment as I need a moment date object for my work. You please ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

> import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';

try this

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was (weirdly) that the z-index of the datepicker's overlay was too high, meaning that any click on the datepicker was actually just clicking on the overlay. Lowering the z-index of it fixed the problem:

```
.cdk-overlay-backdrop {
    z-index: 100; //instead of z-index: 1031;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should import all of this following in 'app.module.ts'

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
```